# Как запросить ввод сообщения после ввода команды TelegramBot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Мне нужно что бы после ввода команды `Погода` 
сначала выводилось вспомогательное сообщение, а *после делалась обработка следующего введённого пользователем сообщения*. Кто знает как это сделать, отпишите пожалуйста.

```
bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton(" Рандомное число")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton(" Как дела?")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("☁️ Погода")

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный чтобы быть подопытным кроликом.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == ' Рандомное число':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0,100)))
        if message.text == '☁️ Погода':
            weather = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи название своего города пожалуйста.")

            @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
            def prognoz(message):
                try:
                    observation = owm.weather_at_place(message.text) 
                    w = observation.get_weather()  
                    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]

                    answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " +  w.get_detailed_status() + "\n"
                    answer += "Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp) + "\n\n"

                    if temp < 10:
                        answer += "Оденься потеплее"
                    elif temp < 20:
                        answer += "Сейчас холодно, надень шапку!"
                    else:
                        answer += "Погода класс!"

                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
                except:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Такого города не существуе, или я его ещё не знаю)\nПожалуйста введите другой город.")
        elif message.text == ' Как дела?':




            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошо", callback_data='good')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Не очень", callback_data='bad')
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Балдежь", callback_data='baldez')
            markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично, сам как?', reply_markup=markup)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вот и отличненько ')
            elif call.data == 'bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Бывает ')
            elif call.data == 'baldez':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Великий балдежь')

            # remove inline buttons
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=" Как дела?",
                reply_markup=None)

            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                text="Боты захватят мир!!11")

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['city'])
def cmd_city(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи город')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, city)
    log(message)

def city(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ищу погоду в городе {city}'.format(city=message.text))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: вот здесь два if подряд]

Мне кажется, что в этой части кода не должно идти два if подряд, нужно прописать if и elif. Но я, конечно, могу ошибаться.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == ' Рандомное число':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0,100)))
        if message.text == '☁️ Погода':
            weather = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи название своего города пожалуйста.")
```